# How to write htaccess seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

I need some rewrite rules for URLs. I Google'd some and applied but no change in URL.

I want:

`http://example.com/tender/details/NIdyzuC41kgt91vRSHHOOFdaPtuMuGL8ePwE0Zx1aEj9vFQecoSRTVRyebazIMxNrUhrJFhK0rJuXpzZ`

Changed to:

```
http://demo.example.com/name-of-topic
```

This is the `.htaccess` file

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have you already changed the URL in your application (to `demo.example.com/name-of-topic`)`? And the `/tender/details/NIdyzuC41kg...` URL is the "real" URL? The slight complication is the subdomain. Does this point to the same area on the file system?

Comment: i dont understand how can i check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a *front controller*, it looks like you should be changing this URL in your application/CMS, not in `.htaccess`?

For the sake of simplicity I will assume that both the main domain `example.com` and the subdomain `demo.example.com` point to the same place on the filesystem. (If they pointed to completely different filesystems then you would need to proxy the request, since you can't simply rewrite across hosts.)

Assuming you've already changed the URL that you link to in the application to `http://demo.example.com/name-of-topic`, then you can add something like the following immediately *after* the `RewriteBase` directive.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^name-of-topic$ /tender/details/NIdyzuC41kgt91vRSHHOOFdaPtuMuGL8ePwE0Zx1aEj9vFQecoSRTVRyebazIMxNrUhrJFhK0rJuXpzZ [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* `http://demo.example.com/name-of-topic` to `/tender/details/NIdyzuC41...` (the "real" URL).